# Django: Annotate and order by foreign key AVG ranking not filtering

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a advertisement model and an review model, related by a `Foreignkey('adfk')` I am trying to get questions having heighest average ranking for their reviews.
For example:
AD1 - Average ranking with 4.
AD2 - Average ranking with 5.

In template the result should show AD2 first and AD1 second.

I am using this in my view but its not showing correctly. DB is postgres. IF I change `('-rating') to ('rating')` it shows Ad1 first and Ad2 second, I mean atleast consider the order_by.

```
def adhome(request,tag_wise=None):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    cities= advertisement.objects.all().values('city').distinct()
    view = request.GET.get('view')

    if tag_wise:
            questionlist=advertisement.objects.filter(tags__slug__in=[tag_wise])
    else:
            questionlist=advertisement.objects.all()

    if view:
        questionlist = questionlist.filter(city=view)

    questionlist = questionlist.annotate(rating=Avg('adfk__rank')).order_by('-rating')



    paginator = Paginator(questionlist,10) # Show 10 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,'classified/home.html',{'contacts':contacts,'tag_wise':tag_wise,'view':view,'tags':tags,'cities':cities,})
```

Comment: Why are you ordering by `id`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I want to show hieghest ranked ads and oldest posted.

Comment: removed id as it does not make any difference.

Comment: Problem is it shows no rating items first and then do the ordering.

Comment: Why do you use `Avg` at all? Each advertisement object has only one adfk, and you aggregate a single value always.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to control the order of NULL and not-NULL values.
There is a [feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html) in PosgreSQL. However it doesn't supported by Django.

But you can do the following:

```
questionlist = questionlist.annotate(rating=Avg('adfk__rank'))
questionlist = questionlist.extra(
    select={'adfk_is_null': 'adfk_id IS NULL'})
questionlist = questionlist.order_by('adfk_is_null', '-rating')
```

P.S. Looks like you are trying to aggregate a single value, so I recommend you to do `F` instead of `Avg`.